# Validating form data using a php file before submission

Tags: php, forms

How can I validate form data before sending? I have a file called `address.php` which checks the data entered to make sure it conforms. Here is my attempt but it's not calling the function upon submit (I don't want to use JS):

```
function validate(){
    include('checkaddress.php'); //checks data conforms
    if (empty($_POST['address']) && checkAddress($_POST['address']) == 0)
    {
        echo ("<fieldset><legend>Invalid Address</legend><p id='form' style='color:red;'><b>Invalid Address </b></fieldset>");
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}


<form method="post" action="address.php">
            <fieldset>
<table style="float:center!improtant; text-align:center!important; margin-left:auto!important;margin-right:auto!important;">
                        <tr><legend>Address</legend></tr>

                <tr><td>
                <label for="email">address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="32" maxlength="128">
                        </tr></td>
                        <tr><td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="return validate();" value="Submit" >
//Call function upon submit. I've tried 'onsubmit="validate();"'
                        </tr></td>

                    </table>
                </fieldset> 
             </form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to do it before you submit the form, you will have to use javascript.

Comment: Its not possible to do anything in php before the form is submitted - php runs on the server

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without javascript.

To validate it with php you need to send it to your server with javascript (e.g. [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) or submit the form and then validate with php.

Honestly, it is usually a better user experience to validate client side, with JS first. That doesn't mean you should not validate server-side (PHP) as well, because you definitely should.

- HTML5 has *some* built-in validation. (http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/)
- Javascript form validation libraries to make your life easier. (http://blog.revrise.com/web-form-validation-javascript-libraries/)